# Is there a way to create a char(13) delimited string that can be used in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I am creating a report in Power BI and would like to create an client address string that is formatted as a standard line-delimited postal address in the United States.

- I tried creating a DAX measure, but could not get around the error:

  `A single value for column 'ServiceAddress1' in table 'pbiCoverPage' cannot be determined.`

This error occurs if I try to use the DAX TRIM function on any TEXT column for a Measure.

- As a workaround, I created a SQL View that returns a `CHAR(13)` delimited string with a postal address.
- However, if I display the field in a card visual, the `CHAR(13)` do not create separate lines.  The postal address is displayed on a single line with the `CHAR(13)` interpreted as a spaces.

My questions are:

1. Can text fields be used at all in DAX Functions such as TRIM in a Measure?
2. Is there a Power BI Visual, other than 'Card' that can display text on a report?
3. Displaying a postal address should not be a difficult task.  Is there a simple way to do this in Power BI?'
4. Is there any way to use a Text Box in Power BI to show a field value?  I think this would allow me to left-justify the address string.
5. If I try to add a Value to a text box, I get a message:

   To turn of Q&A, we need to create a local index of your data.  If you publish the report, we'll one in the service as well.

I am researching this message. It seems like I am driving a tack with a sledge hammer.  Is there an easier way to display a formatted text string in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following approaches:

- **Use a Button**.  The button supports text alignment and has word-wrap.  However, it does not support line delimiters such as `CHAR(10)` or `CHAR(13)`.
- **Use the *HTML Content* Custom Visual from:**

  ```
  https://www.html-content.com/
  ```

The *HTML Content* control allows you to write SQL Queries that return HTML that includes the `<br>` line-break tag.

Thus far, the *HTML Content* visual is the only way (short of a custom R or Python visual) to display a string (such as a postal address) with multiple delimited lines in Power BI.